# Autosys Job setup with both Day and Predecessor conditions

Tags: autosys

Predecessor job(JOB_A) running M-F
JOB_B is set up to run M-TH after JOB_A completion

We have job(JOB_C) that needs to run only on FRIDAY's after JOB_A completion.
Because of FRIDAY only we have to use DATE condition with DAY and TIME.

JOB_C is triggering at the Time and not waiting for the JOB_A completion.
(JOB_A  dependent on another job so it may run any time between 19:00 to 23:00
job run time may be 5Min only)

Can Autosys handle this?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your problem.

From my understanding you want JOB_C to run on Friday, only after the completion of JOB_A in that case you can add the following attributes to the JIL of JOB_C

`days_of_week: fr
conditions: s(JOB_A)`

you can use `conditions : d(JOB_A)` if there is no actual dependency on JOB_A other than the order in which they run.

`d(JOB_A)` is for DONE, that will satisfy the condition as soon as JOB_A had completed irrespective of the exit status/code

`s(JOB_A)` is for SUCCESS, so it will only satisfy if JOB_A had completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a dummy job, let's say JOB_D, just to indicate Friday. The command does not matter, what matter is the schedule - FRIDAY, 00:00. Add this job as a second predecessor for JOB_C with condition SUCCESS IN LAST 24 HOURS - like

```
job: JOB_C
condition: d(JOB_A) & s(JOB_D, 24.00)
...
```